# how to push CS50AI project to GitHub

Tags: github, cs50, git-push

I did upload my degrees Project0 to https://github.com/userid/Project0, I did only Python files
so my question is just uploading file and commit is enough for project submission or I need to do anything else ? is uploading file means pushing code?
I see my files in my GitHub account however it shows 0 submissions in https://submit.cs50.io/courses/187
any one please help if I am missing anything to upload the projects to GitHub
Thanks
Subbu